# Custom taxonomies are not fetched with acf

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have an incomprehensible problem, which is with custom taxonomies, I created a custom taxonomy named "Genre" using the following code:

```
   register_taxonomy( 'genre', 'books', array(
       'label'        => __( 'Genre', 'textdomain' ),
       'rewrite'      => array( 'slug' => 'genre' ),
       'hierarchical' => true,
   ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpdocs_create_book_tax', 0 );
```

And I created a function to get the custom labels as follows:

```
    $terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'genre', 'hide_empty' => false));
    $options = array();

    if (is_array($terms)) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            if (is_object($term)) {
                $options[$term->term_id] = $term->name;
            }
        }
    }

    return $options;
}
```

The problem is when I use it like this to get options, I don't get anything

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array(
     'key' => 'group_book_data',
     'title' => 'book Data',
     'fields' => array(
               array(
 'key' => 'field_book_info',
 'label' => 'book types',
 'name' => 'book_types',
 'type' => 'select',
 'instructions' => 'Select the book category',
 'choices' => get_terms_for_acf_select(),
 'return_format' => 'value', // Change 'label' to 'value'
),
 'location' => array(
         array(
             array(
                 'param' => 'post_type',
                 'operator' => '==',
                 'value' => 'books', 
             ),
         ),
     ),
     'menu_order' => 0,
     'position' => 'normal',
     'style' => 'default',
     'label_placement' => 'top',
     'instruction_placement' => 'label',
 ));
}
```

Knowing that when I change genre to categories, it works normally

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$terms = get_terms( ... )` is populated or empty?

Comment: yes i have items in  Genre